# i want to stay on current cursor location when page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf

I am developing JSF1.2 application. When user make changes in input components, such as h:selectOneMenu, the JSF “value change event” will be called. when it called page is submitting the form and the page is reloaded and the cursor is at top of the page. i want cursor stay at previous position. below is the code for h:selectOneMenu.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}" onchange="this.form.submit()"
    valueChangeListener="#{bean.valueChangeMethod}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.values}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

how can i solve it? i haven't given any scripting in XHTML file. please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify JSF version, here's a **JSF2** solution:

If you make it an AJAX call, the scroll of the page will remain the same. Here's an example:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.values}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{...}" render="id1 id2 id3 ..." />    
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

`id1 id2 id3 ...` are the components' ids you want to rerender after the AJAX call. You can put `@all` to refresh the whole page or `@form` to refresh the current form.

You can learn more about `<f:ajax />` [here](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/).

Comment: thanks for the reply. Sorry i haven't mentioned my jsf version. I am working on jsf 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

If what you seek is to get the mouse position on page refresh, this is **impossible** to do.

For now anyway. you can however capture the `onmousemove` event which will tell you where the cursor is on the screen and save that location, but you cannot manipulate the mouse to move on it's own.

However if there is a textfield that you want focussed you could always use JS `focus();` method onpageload.

**EDIT**

As for the OP's general question.

This is not possible, it's browser dependand. Usually your cursor stays where it is in any normal modern browser. With older browsers **or IE** the behaviour will be abit different.

The reason for this not being possible is because the mouse position will be unknown on page refresh, thus you cannot relocate it even if it was possible.

Hope this helps

‐ Sid

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, in my XHTML page I have a custom list page, where a user can add few Characteristics, so it spreads more than one page. when i Scroll down to second page, if i selected h:selectOneMenu option then page refreshed and cursor goes to the top of the page. i want the cursor has to stay on the previous position when the page refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

This flickering problem can be solved by  ajax. For  Ajax  add the following jars to lib  folder:

- ajax4jsf-1.0.6.jar
- commons-beanutils.jar
- commons-digester-1.7.jar
- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.oscache-2.4_1.jar

Add  following  code  in web.xml file

```
<filter>         
  <display-name>Ajax4jsf Filter</display-name>        
  <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>         
  <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>     
</filter>       

<filter-mapping>         
  <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>         
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>        
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>         
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>         
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>     
</filter-mapping>
```

And add following  line to your .jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="a4j" uri="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax"%>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually i am using xhtml file instead of jsp. So please tell me how to add this taglib to xhtml.

Comment: sorry i overlooked you xhtml part. For  xhtml  pages you could use  <html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:a4j="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax">.  just add  these.